# How should a backslash resulting from variable expansion be treated?

Tags: shell, sh, posix

I ran the following command (`*sh` being the name of a `sh` implementation) with all the shells I could find; although I was expecting all to print `match`, I got inconsistent results. I don't know which behavior is correct and reliable.

```
*sh -c 'case "$1" in $2) echo match; esac' _ 'f\oo' 'f\\oo'
```

---

With [dash from Ubuntu bionic's repo](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/dash) (and ash; which is a symbolic link to dash)

```
$ dash -c 'case "$1" in $2) echo match; esac' _ 'f\oo' 'f\\oo'
match
```

With bash 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) and 5.0.11(1)-release (arm-unknown-linux-androideabi)

```
$ bash -c 'case "$1" in $2) echo match; esac' _ 'f\oo' 'f\\oo'
match
```

With ksh Version AJM 93u+ 2012-08-01, and Version JM 93t+ 2010-03-05 (comes preinstalled with SunOS omniosce 5.11)

```
$ ksh -c 'case "$1" in $2) echo match; esac' _ 'f\oo' 'f\\oo'
match
```

With ksh @(#)PD KSH v5.2.14 99.07.13.2 (the default shell on OpenBSD 6.6, and [its Linux port](https://github.com/dimkr/loksh/))

```
$ ksh -c 'case "$1" in $2) echo match; esac' _ 'f\oo' 'f\\oo'
$
```

With lksh @(#)LEGACY KSH R56 2018/01/14, mksh @(#)MIRBSD KSH R56 2018/01/14 (these are different binaries on Ubuntu bionic), and mksh @(#)MIRBSD KSH R57 2019/03/01

```
$ lksh -c 'case "$1" in $2) echo match; esac' _ 'f\oo' 'f\\oo'
$ mksh -c 'case "$1" in $2) echo match; esac' _ 'f\oo' 'f\\oo'
$
```

With posh 0.13.1

```
$ posh -c 'case "$1" in $2) echo match; esac' _ 'f\oo' 'f\\oo'
$
```

With yash 2.46

```
$ yash -c 'case "$1" in $2) echo match; esac' _ 'f\oo' 'f\\oo'
$
```

And with zsh 5.4.2 (x86_64-ubuntu-linux-gnu) and 5.7.1 (arm-unknown-linux-androideabi); emulating sh

```
$ zsh -c 'emulate sh; case "$1" in $2) echo match; esac' _ 'f\oo' 'f\\oo'
match
```

---

And I'm lost in [POSIX's Shell Command Language specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18)<sup>†</sup>; couldn't find a straightforward answer to my question yet: **How should an escaped backslash resulting from a variable expansion be interpreted in a glob pattern? As `\\` or as `\`?** Or is it unspecified?

---

<sup>†</sup> Under [Case Conditional Construct](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04_05) it says:

> In order from the beginning to the end of the case statement, each *pattern* that labels a compound-list shall be subjected to tilde expansion, parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion, and the result of these expansions shall be compared against the expansion of word, according to the rules described in [Pattern Matching Notation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13) (**which also describes the effect of quoting parts of the pattern**)

Notice it doesn't say patterns are subjected to quote removal; but under Pattern Matching Notation, it says:

> A <backslash> character shall escape the following character. The escaping <backslash> shall be discarded

But it doesn't clarify if that still happens when the pattern is a result of expansion.

---

For anyone who's interested, the standard is unclear on this; they'll amend it in newer versions though. Below are some links to POSIX bug reports where this issue was discussed broadly.

- [0001234: in most shells, backslash doesn't have two meaning wrt pattern matching](https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=1234)
- [0001190: backslash has two special meanings in the shell and only loses one of them in bracket expressions](https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=1190)
- [0000985: quote removal missing from case statement patterns and alternative expansions](https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=985)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this bit of reference can clear things up for your question. From the [POSIX's Shell Command Language specification - under Pattern Matching Notation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18) the clause states,

> 2.13.1 **Patterns Matching a Single Character**
>
> A `<backslash>` character shall escape the following character. The escaping `<backslash>` shall be discarded. If a pattern ends with an unescaped `<backslash>`, it is unspecified whether the pattern does not match anything or the pattern is treated as invalid

The above rule applies to patterns while using the `case` statements and when using the the `==` glob match operator in `bash` using `test` construct.

So since your `$2` remains unquoted while undergoing pattern match, the literal value of `f\\oo` is lost forever and gets interpreted as `f\oo`.

Just to clear things up, the shell has preserved your literal value during quote removal and just when applying the passed argument in this pattern matching rule, this behavior is exhibited.

Comment: So, it's just ksh and its clones being buggy?

Comment: And what posix says is, *pattern* is subjected to expansions during parsing, and the backslash is removed by pattern matching mechanism, right?

Comment: @oguzismail: Yes added a note now. I've only used `ksh93` which used to be almost POSIX compatible. Not sure about the rest of them though

Comment: Okay, thanks for elaborating. I'll look for additional evidence backing up what you've said, so don't get pissed if I don't accept this today

Comment: @oguzismail: no problem! Great work trying to find answers to intricate unknowns in the language. Keep up the good work~