# Why does wildcard pattern not match for escaped backslach

Tags: bash, wildcard, glob

I have the following bash script where I am testing some wildcard pattern matching and expected all of the calls to `test` to echo `match`.  I do not understand why the last case does not match:

```
#!/bin/bash

test () {
  subject=$1
  pattern=$2
  echo "----------------"
  echo "$subject vs $pattern"
  case $subject in
    ($pattern) echo "match";;
    (*)        echo "no match";;
  esac
}

# Test question mark
test "a" "?"

# Test asterisk
test "foobar" "*"

# Test literal
test "a" "a"

# Test backslash
test "\\" "\\"
```

Output:

```
$ ./example.sh
----------------
a vs ?
match
----------------
foobar vs *
match
----------------
a vs a
match
----------------
\ vs \
no match
```

---

I understand that the backslash is used for escaping, but I do not understand why the subject and pattern do not match when they are the same `"\\"` - shouldn't they be escaped in the same way?

Comment: By the way, as a general comment, using `test` as the name of a function of yours is a terrible choice. `test` is built-in unix utility (is the one that is used when you do `[ expression ]`, but you can also use its name).

Comment: Thanks, I will note that for the future.

Comment: When I approached linux, you have no idea how long I did spend to realize my `test` program was giving strange error: I was executing `test` rather than `./test`.

Comment: You might also want to have a look at [How should a backslash resulting from variable expansion be treated?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59348035/5291015)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `test "\\" "\\"` what the function received in $1 and $2 is a string containing a single backslash.

If you do `if [ $subject = $pattern ]; then ...` it works because there is no pattern matching.

But pattern matching means that the single backslash in the PATTERN string must escape something - a single backslash by itself is not valid.  That's why your case statement didn't work.

If the PATTERN were a string containing two backslashes then the first would escape the second and it would match a SUBJECT string containing one backslash.

Your case statement in the last test is equivalent to:

```
case "\\" in (\) echo "match"; esac
```

Which can't work because the backslash in the patter must escape something.

But this would work:

```
case "\\" in (\\) echo "match"; esac
```

So a test that works is:

```
test "\\" "\\\\"
```

Comment: Thanks, the bit about the single backslash being invalid was the piece I was missing.